# Change coordinates to bottom left corner

Tags: java, java-2d, coordinate

How can I change coordinates to bottom left corner?

I know that's in Java the coordinates begin from Top=Left corner, but I'm asking if can someone help me how can I change it to begin (0,0) coordinates from Bottom-Left corner?

Comment: bottom left corner of what? monitor? some component? or??

Comment: @Tomas Bisciak of the monitor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getHeight()` will get you the size height. so `(0, getHeight())` will give you the left-bottom point. But take into consideration the height of the object you want to place. So you may want to use

```
(0, getHeight() - heightOfObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's too late, but for people like me (new to android development). The above answers are correct but here is a more detailed one

If you get the coordinate with respect to top left as (a,b),
then the coordinates with respect to the bottom left are simply
`(a, h-b)` where h is the height of the view.

Example:

```
float x = getXcoordinatesonTouch();
float y = getYcoordinatesonTouch();

//should return height
float h = getHeightoftheView();

float transformY = h - y;

//"x" should be as it is
//Now you can show "x" and "transformY"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the value `(x, HEIGHT - y)`.